# TableView not display data in angular js

Tags: angularjs, tableview

Hi I am a beginner for Angular-Js and I am trying to display Array data in table view using below code but **data is not displaying**.

What mistake did I make?

I followed below link for doing my requirement:

https://lorenzofox3.github.io/smart-table-website/

### index.htmlk:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="bootstrap-css@3.2.0" data-semver="3.2.0" rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.21" data-semver="1.2.21" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.21/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="app.js"></script>
    <script src="smart-table.js"></script>
    <script src="IrInfiniteScrollPlugin.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>

  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="safeCtrl">

  <table st-table="rowCollection" class="table table-striped">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>first name</th>
        <th>last name</th>
        <th>birth date</th>
        <th>balance</th>
        <th>email</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
        <td>{{row.firstName | uppercase}}</td>
        <td>{{row.lastName}}</td>
        <td>{{row.birthDate | date}}</td>
        <td>{{row.balance | currency}}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-sm" popover-placement="top" popover="{{row.email}}" type="button">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i>
            </button>
            <a ng-href="mailto:{{row.email}}">email</a></td>
        <td>
            <button type="button" ng-click="removeRow(row)" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle">
                </i>
            </button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>

  </div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

### app.js:

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('safeCtrl', function($scope) {

    scope.rowCollection = [
        {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
    ];
});
```

Comment: you are not using it yet. You need to inject the module into your with `angular.module('myApp', ['smart-table'])`

Answer (score 1):

I think you missed to inject `$scope` OR it's not injected properly. Try below controller code, might this will help you.

```
angular.module('myApp', []).controller('safeCtrl',['$scope', function(scope) {
    scope.rowCollection = [
        {firstName: 'Laurent', lastName: 'Renard', birthDate: new Date('1987-05-21'), balance: 102, email: 'whatever@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Blandine', lastName: 'Faivre', birthDate: new Date('1987-04-25'), balance: -2323.22, email: 'oufblandou@gmail.com'},
        {firstName: 'Francoise', lastName: 'Frere', birthDate: new Date('1955-08-27'), balance: 42343, email: 'raymondef@gmail.com'}
    ];
}]);
```

> NOTE: Hopefully, you fulfill the first requirement of this injects of
>   the library. i.e. The first thing is to add the module
>   angular.module('myApp',['smart-table'] to your angular application.

Hope this will help to solve!